# Flip array data values - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I flip the array data values (based on Y values) so when I am plotting it will be like a mirror plot? (instead of looking like a “mountain” it will look like a “valley”)

Code:

```
clc
clear 
close all

y   = [4 5 6 9 10 20 22 25 22 20  15 10 0];
x  = 0:12;
data = rot90(cat(1, x, y));
flipData = flip(data);
figure('Name','Data','NumberTitle','off');
plot(data(:,1),data(:,2),'r','LineWidth',2); 
figure('Name','Flip Data','NumberTitle','off');
plot(flipData(:,1),flipData(:,2),'r','LineWidth',2);
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `plot(x,-y)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot `max(y) - y`:

```
y2 = max(y) - y;
plot(x, y2, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

Comment: I wish to flip the data, not the plot itself.

Comment: The commend flip both x and y, how can I only flip the y?

Comment: I edited my post again, starting from original `x` any `y`.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the direction of the axis, so that your graph is upside down, but Y-values are still correct.

```matlab
y   = [4 5 6 9 10 20 22 25 22 20 15 10 0];
x  = 0:12;
data = rot90(cat(1, x, y));

figure('Name','Data','NumberTitle','off');
plot(data(:,1),data(:,2),'r','LineWidth',2); 

figure('Name','max(y) - y','NumberTitle','off');
y2 = max(y) - y;
plot(x, y2, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);

figure('Name','ax.YDir reverse','NumberTitle','off');
plot(data(:,1),data(:,2),'r','LineWidth',2);
ax = gca;
ax.YDir = 'reverse';
```

[image: matlab graphs]